Nginx try_files is giving 404 instead serving from folder location
I am running nginx as container my static data like images are in data folder. The docker files copies the data folder to the root directory.

when calling request http://localhost/data/trabajos/dino/Img138.gif my understading is it will try to find the file /data/trabajos/dino/Img138.gif in data folder and serve it. But I get 404. Am I doing something wrong or using try_files wrong
nginx default.conf
server {

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    }

